# Passing non-AR for form_for in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to do this in login form,
I just want to keep the data when user submit the data, but which is not valid.

The codes below:

in controller:

```
def login

    if request.request_method == "POST"
        @session = params[:session]
    end

    render "login",
           :layout => "admin_login"
end
```

and the `admin_login` tempaltes:

```
= form_for :session, :url => { :action => "login", :controller => "administrator" }, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" } do |f|

  %div.control-group
    #{f.label :token, "User / Email", :class => "control-label" }
    %div.controls
      #{f.text_field :token}

  %div.control-group
    #{f.label :password, "Password", :class => "control-label" }
    %div.controls
      #{f.password_field :password}
```

But it will throw a exception when I submit the form, said `undefined method 'token'`

Thanks

Comment: you said its complaining `undefined method 'token'`, but I am seeing that your `token` field is commented in the above code?

Comment: nope. he's using haml so that code is perfectly valid.

Comment: haml..oh I see. I didn't knew about that. Thanks!

Comment: although for 1 line which uses some coding, he should've used `=` like in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not dealing with a resource, you should use `form_tag`

```
= form_tag { action: 'login', controller: 'administrator' }, class: 'form-horizontal' do
  %div.control-group
    %label.control-label User / Email

    %div.controls
      = text_field_tag :token

  %div.control-group
    %label.control-label Password

    %div.controls
      = password_field_tag :password
```

Comment: thanks~  you mean if not using Resource for REST, the way I do is impossible ?

Comment: It should be `form_tag` but you used `form_for` above?

Comment: thanks Saurabh, fixed. Francis, it's still possible but you should use  the `_tag` forms of the form helpers.